# How is this configuration in Raft algorithm correct

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed, consensus, raft

So lets suppose that the log configuration for 3 servers in the raft algorithm is as follows:

S1 -> 3

S2 -> 3 3 4

S3 -> 3 3 5

This configuration can arise if let's say S3 is the leader in term 3 the entry was committed with every replica, then in another client operation with the same leader S3, it is only able to replicate the entry in S2 and itself and then it crashes. After that S2 wins the election with votes from itself and S1. It gets an entry and enters it to the log and then crashes. S3 comes back again and then gets vote from S1 and itself and becomes a leader, enters another log in term 5 and then crashes.

Now we have a situation in which entries in term 4 and 5 are definitely not committed. Lets say S2 becomes leader again(getting vote from itself and S1), It will try to correct the logs in the followers and would end up overwriting and appending to both followers to get:

S1 -> 3 3 4

S2 -> 3 3 4

S3 -> 3 3 4

In my reasoning it is fair to remove the log in term 5 because the leader might not have responded with a done message ever to the client as the replication of entry in term 5 was not done on majority of servers. But isn't the same argument valid for entry in term 4, and if so why is it replicated everywhere. The client wouldn't have got a done response for the entry in term 4 either so the client would think the state machine would not run this operation, but through the above logic it does.

Someone care to explain please?

Comment: you could also try asking this question at cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

"After that S2 wins the election with votes from itself and S1. It gets an entry and enters it to the log"

When a node becomes a leader, it is guaranteed that it has most up to date log; and the log has both proposed and committed entries.
Before the new leader processes requests, it pings every follower with an empty message; that message carries log information and the leader may conclude if some followers are behind. For those who are behind, the leader will ship all missing entries.

At that point the leader and the majority has same logs and the leader may continue with committing non committed entries; and then accept new requests.

Check the original paper: https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf page 4 - AppendEntries RPC: Receiver implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Step #1. Initial state, S3 leader all ok, index 10 committed

```
      10   11   12  
S1 -> 3
S2 -> 3
S3 -> 3
```

Step #2. then in another client operation with the same leader S3, it is only able to replicate the entry in S2 and itself and then it crashes.

```
      10   11   12  
S1 -> 3               // S1 crashed
S2 -> 3    3
S3 -> 3    3
```

Step #3. After that S2 wins the election with votes from itself and S1. It gets an entry and enters it to the log and then crashes.

```
      10   11   12  
S1 -> 3             // S1 came back up, now at term 4         
S2 -> 3    3    4   // S2 is new leader (term 4), got entry at Index 12,crashed
S3 -> 3    3        // S3 (old leader) crashed, is down and election started
```

Step #4. S3 comes back again and then gets vote from S1 and itself and becomes a leader, enters another log in term 5 and then crashes.

```
      10   11   12  
S1 -> 3             // S1 is up at term 5
S2 -> 3    3    4   // S2 is down
S3 -> 3    3    5   // new election term 5, becomes leader, gets entry at 12
```

But the real question is in Step #4, why S3 was chosen as leader? Its last known term was only 3, because while term went to 4, S3 was down.